# how do i add a comment to an xpath?

Tags: xpath

for example i have an xpath and wish to add a comment near it to identify it.

```
/html/body/div/table/tr/td/a{this is a link}
```

Comment: Where do you have the XPath? What language are you using it from? What is that language's comment syntax?

Comment: i mean is it possible to add comments naively to an xpath.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not a comment syntax, but you can give string literals as predicate, which evaluates as true (imho) and should not change the outcome of the expression. I don't know if this has big performance drawbacks.

```
/html/body/div/table["this is"]["a table"]/tr/td/a["this is a link"]
```

But like mjv said, I also would stick to the syntax of the host language.

Comment: Logged in just to upvote this ancient answer. Genius!

Answer (score 23):

XPATH 2.0 does allow comments.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#comments:

> Comments may be used to provide informative annotation for an
>   expression. Comments are lexical constructs only, and do not affect
>   expression processing.
>
> Comments are strings, delimited by the symbols `(:` and `:)`. Comments may
>   be nested.
>
> A comment may be used anywhere ignorable whitespace is allowed (see
>   A.2.4.1 Default Whitespace Handling).
>
> The following is an example of a comment:
>
> `(: Houston, we have a problem :)`

Bad news if we ever need to parse XML containing emoticons! :-)

As an aside - as I was looking for this info in the context of working with Tibco Designer for BusinessWorks v5.x, where comments can be added within the TIBCO Designer XPATH formula builder using:

`{-- Houston, we've had a problem --}`

Comment: This should be the marked answer. Works just fine with Saxon HE 9.6.

Answer (score 7):

**2019 edit**
As pointed out in @Sepster's reply and elsewhere, starting with ***XPath 2.0***, comments became possible with their cute "smiley face"-looking syntax.  I'm only about 10 years late in editing this reply to mention very useful fact ;-)

**Original reply c. 2009 (assumed XPATH 1.0)**
No, the XPATH syntax doesn't allow to embed comments within the path string.

This is typically not a significant limitation because paths are usually short and a comment can be placed nearby, in the particular syntax of the host language (XSLT, C#, whatever...)

Comment: The XPath 1.0 specification does not allow comments. However, XPath 2.0 does allow comments `(: this will be a comment in XPath 2.0 :)`